# SignalR in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, signalr

I am trying to setup SignalR using Visual Basic.  This is very difficult because every example (literally every example) is in C#.  I'm doing an okay job getting through conversions, but I am stumped on this:

```
[HubName("ThisHub")]
```

What is the VB equivalent for this?  This is for creating the proxy name of the hub.

Comment: isnt it simply `<HubName("ThisHub")>` ?

Comment: Of course it's that simple.  Ugh.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the rewards :)

Its simply:-

```
<HubName("ThisHub")>
```

Comment: Since I have you here, can you also help me with this line:

Public StockTickerHub() :  this(StockTicker.Instance) { }

Comment: Ask a new question, with more context. Be easier

Answer (score 2):

Rippo answered this:

<HubName("ThisHub")>